# Using WP Query to search within ALL keys in meta query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

What is the best way to create a meta query that searches through ALL meta fields (keys)? What I'm trying to do is something such as:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
        array(
            'key' => ALL,
            'value' => keyword
        )
    )
));
```

Does that make sense? What is the proper way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, just maybe if you remove `key` and add `compare => 'LIKE'` - but there isn't a "select all" or wildcard for keys in `meta_query`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Howdy_McGee](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7355/howdy-mcgee) suggested and I made a quick test. Removing `key` do the trick so you can just remove the `key` and add compare `LIKE` if you do not want exact match.

Example:-

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 'meta_value'
        )
    )
));
```

This will produce the SQL like

```
WHERE 1=1  AND ( CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'meta_value' )
```

That is what we want!

Comment: Just remember, `LIKE` comparisons are quite expensive

Comment: Yes 100% true and also you may get undesired slow results because matching all the keys including the hidden one :)